# fileinput-preview get details from image

Tags: javascript, php, file-io

I using bootstrap-fileinput to load an image to my project. Is it possible to get the image details like the size, resolution, etc?

My code is:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
            <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" >
                <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" style="width:200px;height:150px" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" id="imagem" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;">
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="btn default btn-file">
                <span class="fileinput-new">Escolher imagem </span>
                <span class="fileinput-exists">Alterar </span>
                  <input id="imagem" type="file" name="...">
                </span>
                <a id="btnRemoverImagemCapa" href="#" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remover </a>
           </div>
    </div>
```